# Background image cannot be found java cycloon

Tags: css, tomcat, web

I'm working on a web project, and whilst testing with our server I ran into an error. Whilst testing using localhost, everything works fine. However when I upload it on a server using a WAR file, the background images don't show. Using dev-tools (network) i figured out that the images cannot be found. The images are in the same folder as the others (which have been loaded in using the JSP-page, not the css page).

```
<td class="edit"><a href="#"></a></td>
```

That's how the html tag looks like.
And below follows the CSS.

```
.edit a{background:url("/pic/Editing-Edit-icon.png") no-repeat #B9B9B9;}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: the problem is that the server asks for these pictures from the server: `server/pic`, instead it should search for `server/TestVx.x/pic`

Comment: does your server have the same file structure as your local dev environment, ie is the pic folder still in the root of the site on the server?  If so, is your server set up to serve png files?

Comment: Can you give details on "I ran into an error."?

Comment: It's a school server, so I don't really know how it is set up, I assume the pic folder is still in the root of the server, it may be the PNG-images, i'll check. @Pete

Comment: The pictures don't show, that's the error @U.Windl

Comment: @Andreas: The picture not being shown is not the error, but the consequence of an error. You must explain the problem so that it can be solved. "Image not displayed" is most likely not a problem that can be solved. "File not found" is different, however.

Comment: @Pete It's not the PNG format that stops it from working, I think it might be the fact that I try to call an image from the css

Comment: @U.Windl in the network tab from chrome dev tools it says: '404 file not found'

Comment: And is the network path to the image what you would expect (and the same as the image that works)?

Comment: Request header:
- refer: Referer: ...TestV1.2/css/css.css
General:
-Request URL: .../pic/Editing-Edit-icon.png

Comment: the TestV1.2 part has gone that's the problem